# c++ enum scope failed to compile with -std=c++98, but ok with -std=c++11

Tags: c++, class, c++11, enums, c++98

A simple program as below, no c++11 syntax at all (e.cpp)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace m{
class my{
public:
    enum A{
        u=1,
        v=2,
        w=3
    };
    static A f(A a){
        return (A)(a + A::u);
    }
};
int main(){
    using namespace m;
    my::A r=my::f(my::u);
    return 0;
}
```

Using g++4.1.2 to compile it:

```
e.cpp:17:2: warning: no newline at end of file
e.cpp: In static member function ‘static m::my::A m::my::f(m::my::A)’:
e.cpp:11: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
e.cpp:11: error: ‘A’ is not a class or namespace
```

Using g++4.9.2 with -std=c++98

```
g++ e.cpp -std=c++98
e.cpp: In static member function ‘static m::my::A m::my::f(m::my::A)’:
e.cpp:11:36: error: ‘A’ is not a class or namespace
    static A f(A a){return (A)(a + A::u);}
                                    ^
```

But using -std=c++11 is ok:

```
g++ e.cpp -std=c++11
```

To make it compile using c++98, I change it to avoid "A::" to be:

```
static A f(A a){return (A)(a + u);}
```

So seems that under c++98, the embeded enum class is not recognized inside a class, while in c++11 it works. Is this a difference in enum resolution, or some previous syntax bug in c++98 standard?

Comment: There is no such thing as "enum class" in C++98.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enum values are not scoped by the enum type (either in C++98 or C++11). In the following example:

```
namespace N {
    enum E { X };
}
```

`X` is directly in the scope of namespace `N`. Its fully qualified identifier would be `::N::X`.

This behaviour was changed by C++11, where following the same definition, the  identifier of `X` can **also** be referred using `::N::E::X`:

> #### [`[dcl.enum/11]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#11.sentence-4)
>
> An enumerator declared in class scope can be referred to using the class member access
>   operators (`::`, `.` (dot) and `->` (arrow)), see 5.2.5. [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct X {
>     enum direction { left=’l’, right=’r’ };
>     int f(int i) { return i==left ? 0 : i==right ? 1 : 2; }
> };
>
> void g(X* p) {
>     direction d; // error: direction not in scope
>     int i;
>     i = p->f(left); // error: left not in scope
>     i = p->f(X::right); // OK
>     i = p->f(p->left); // OK
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> —end example ]

Answer (score 3):

The enumeration name could not be used to qualify an enumerator prior to C++11. So there is no bug in C++98 mode, the code is just ill-formed.

You are correct in deducing the rules have changed.

The C++ FAQ [lists the changes made to enumerations in C++11](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language-types#enum-class), and cites the proposals that drove those changes.